# Please explain how the remainder operator works here?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how the `== 0` works with the `remainder` part of the code, for example `(4+4) % 2 == 0`, wouldn't that come out as 4 yet this code gives it a `true`, `false`, `true`, `false`, etc.

```
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += " ";
    else
      board += "#";
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

Comment: 8 modulus 2 equals 0, which matches the conditional of == 0

Comment: What would come out as 4? `4 + 4` is `8`. And `8 % 2` is `0`. So `(4 + 4) % 2 == 0` is `true`. What exactly don’t you understand there?

Comment: @NisalEdu This isn’t Java. The correct resource is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder).

Comment: @Xufox I understand that that example comes out as 0 but the previous is also 0 yet it is suppose to be an on/off type but wouldn't (3+3) % 2 == 0 as well?

Comment: @ajhernandez95 Yes, of course. `3 + 3` is `6`. But this isn’t the “previous” calculation. There are also `(3 + 4) % 2 == 1` and `(4 + 3) % 2 == 1`.

Comment: @Xufox I thought it looped through iterating 1 each time at the same time so x and y would become 1,1 2,2 3,3 4,4 etc

Comment: @ajhernandez95 No, this is not the case. This is a nested `for` loop. Before `y` is equal to `1`, `x` first has to loop from `0` to `7`. So it increments like this: `0, 0`, `1, 0`, `2, 0`, …, `7, 0`, `0, 1`, `1, 1`, `2, 1`…

Comment: @Xufox OHH, okay I was confused on that part so the most nested loop iterates first then the next?

Comment: @ajhernandez95 Yes.

Comment: @Xufox Okay, sorry for the stupidity of that I am still fairly new to javascript but thank you that has cleared up the whole thing for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Think of %(modulo) as the 'remainder' when there is a division'
>
> Let me give you a couple of instances...
>
> 10 % 2 = 0; //2 will go into 10, five times a leave a remainder of 0
>
> 12 % 2 = 0; //2 will go into 12, six times and leave a remainder of 0
>
> 5%2 = 1;// 2 will go into 5, 2 times and leave a remainder of 1
>
> 6%3   = 0; // 3 will go into 6, 2 times and leave a remainder of 0
>
> 3%5   = 3; //5 cant go into 3, so the remainder is 3. That's the same
> number
>
> (4+4)%2 =  0 // 8%2 = 0 .....2 will go into 8, four times and leave a
> remainder of 0

Comment: Where are you quoting this text from?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += " ";
    else
      board += "#";
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

Works as expected.

The modulus operator returns the remainder. You will create a checker board pattern with this. If you want to reverse it, use `=== 1`. If you want it to be the same on each row, just use `x%2 === 0` or `x%2 === 1`

Answer (score 0):

(4 + 4) % 2

8 / 2 = 4

and remaining value is 0

operation will give us remaining value after division

10 % 17 = 10

When we using long division for above case,

1) Find number of 17s in 10 answer is 0

2) Then 10 - (0 * 17) = 10

Answer (score 0):

`%` is the modulus operation. It will will return whatever is left after the number is divided by the operand. So `(4+4)%2` is the same as `8%2`. And as 2 goes into 8 exactly (with no reminder) it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are misunderstanding how [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) works. This example should print out what each iterations modulus remainder is. If the left side of the equation divides with no remainder then you get a 0.

```js
const size = 8;

let board = "";

for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    console.log(x + ' plus ' + y + ' (' + (x+y) +') modulus 2 equals ' + (x + y) %2);
    board += ((x + y) % 2 === 0) ? " " : "#";
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

Comment: It turns out, he’s misunderstanding how nested `for` loops work.